# Proxy tag not matching URL as intended

Tags: angular, proxy

I have an Angular app trying to connect to a web service hosted in a Java app via a Tomcat server. When the page loads, it tries to contact one of the service endpoints and at best, gets an HTTP 404, other times the service call gets blocked due to CORS restrictions.

In short, I want to have Java services hosted at localhost:8090, accessible by this Angular app.  An example service is:

http://localhost:8090/sc-reporting/ldap

I believe the Java services are working, but cannot even get them to be reached by the Angular driven code.

The local environment file is:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8090/proxy'
  };
```

The base environment file is:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8090/proxy'
};
```

The service offending service call does:

```
return this.http.post(environment.baseUrl + '/ldap/getUserProfile', '{"user_id":\"'+userid+'\"}', httpOptions);
```

A snippet of angular.json with the proxy info is:

```
               "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "admin-tool:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "prod": {
                            "browserTarget": "admin-tool:build:prod"
                        },
                        "dev": {
                            "browserTarget": "admin-tool:build:dev",
                            "proxyConfig": "dev-proxy-config.json"
                        },
                        "stage": {
                            "browserTarget": "admin-tool:build:stage"
                        },
                        "local": {
                            "browserTarget": "admin-tool:build:local",
                            "proxyConfig": "local-proxy-config.json"
                        }
                    }
```

Finally the proxy config file local-proxy-config.json is

```
{
    "/proxy/*": {
        "target": 'http://localhost:8090'
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {'/proxy': '/sc-reporting'} ,
    }

}
```

I don't know if the secure property refers to the URL incoming URL or the URL that the request is being proxied to.  LogLevel only mentions that I tried to do a proxy, but it doesn't show the actual requests and (mis)matches.  I assume changeOrigin would likely always be true, so I'm not sure that needs to be specified.

This is for local non-production development mode, where the server is started with

```
  ng serve --configuration=local
```

Upon starting, Angular console shows:

```
$ ng serve --configuration=local
Your global Angular CLI version (8.0.2) is greater than your local
version (7.3.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
[HPM] Proxy created: /  ->  http://localhost:8090
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-07-03T16:44:24.017Z
Hash: a6444379feddc404c22b
Time: 113614ms
chunk {0} 0.fa0122fa52d24925d111.js, 0.fa0122fa52d24925d111.js.map () 215 kB  [rendered]
chunk {main} main.2dd6a44d76e8b77fa0a8.js, main.2dd6a44d76e8b77fa0a8.js.map (main) 8.25 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.0311b8e71410fdde5f64.js, polyfills.0311b8e71410fdde5f64.js.map (polyfills) 158 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.1bb23cf2a48df72b603f.js, runtime.1bb23cf2a48df72b603f.js.map (runtime) 8.8 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.00f56f46ef424e79bc34.js, scripts.00f56f46ef424e79bc34.js.map (scripts) 703 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.d833da89befc273a6b3b.css, styles.d833da89befc273a6b3b.css.map (styles) 789 kB [initial] [rendered]
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

I tried using the approach outlined at https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d, which I believe to be out of the box proxy support for Angular. I also tried the multiple entry format described at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy#multiple-entries.

This is for local development mode, wherein the

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the proxy configuration file to

```
{
    "/proxy/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8090/ROOT/",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": { "^/proxy": "" }
    }
}
```

Note, I still don't know whether the secure property refers to the destination URL or the incoming URL which would be proxied.  I also don't understand why there's a changeOrigin property if I already had to specify the new origin in the target property.